# Clicking on Cancel just refreshes the page when you are logged in and not have participated in a community and click on Ask a question

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Let's say I take Math Meta SE. As you can see from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNQOC.png) image I haven't joined the site and I click on Ask question. It shows me this page

[image: ![account confirmation screen]

If then I click on cancel the page just refreshes and doesn't take me back to the original page. Please fix this.

Comment: What is the "original" page you expect to go back to? It can't bring you back to /questions/ask because you decided to not create an account and you need one to do anything useful on the /questions/ask page. I doubt the Cancel route has any meaningful way to redirect to something useful.

Comment: @rene in that case there shouldn't be a cancel button. Or maybe they can change it to "Nevermind, take me to the question list" and link it accordingly.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I'm not sure on which routes you can trigger account creation. Sending users to a default page they have not seen earlier is not a great UX either. I don't see much wrong in reacting to Cancel to actually Cancel all UX flow and let the user get their bearing again by their selves.

Comment: Interestingly, cancel throws *me* into the front page of the site - both with google and 'SE' logins... I can't replicate this, or the dupe

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I can only repro on some sites - which sites are you trying?

Comment: Cardano - I assumed it's the same flow

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Cardano has the default of not requiring registration to ask a question (I assume), whereas [Math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/lets-require-registration-to-ask-a-question) and [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2626), for example, do. Maybe that's a difference? (I can't repro on Cardano but can on the latter two)

Comment: No repro on math with my sock either

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Just to make sure.. this is happening when you click the "Ask Question" button on a site you haven't joined. *Not* the "Join this community" button. The reason is that clicking cancel brings you back to whatever page you were on. So if you were on the front page, it will bring you back to the front page. But if you were on the "Ask Question" page, it will still show the "Confirm your new account" prompt. Sort of an infinite loop.

Comment: @rene that's why I specifically worded the button to say "take me to the question list". I imagine it being like the 404 page (for example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/fdasfasdfsd). It doesn't know where to take you so it gives you options. Such as "Browse our recent questions"